# Neural network, why do we sum the bias along axis 0 (np.sum(..., axis=0)) when doing batch gradient descent?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network, pytorch

I'm having a lot of troubles understanding why we have to do np.sum(..., axis=0) when we are computing the gradients of bias w.r.t. loss in a Neural Net.

I'm studying with a book and there's this nice 2-layer NN diagram:

[image]

now, if I want to know by how much I have to update (for example) B_2, I just do:

gradient of bias wrt loss = `∂(L)/∂(b_2) = ∂(L)/∂(P) * ∂(P)/∂(b_2) = -(Y - P) * np.ones_like(b_2)`

Then just `bias -= LR * (gradient of bias wrt loss)`.

And that's it, no? Where is calculus saying that we have to sum along the axis 0?